# Little endian and push in nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, endianness

I don't understand why the output of the code is **Ole**. Shouldn't little endianness affect the **push** command?

```
global _start

  section .data
x: dd 3

section .text
_start:
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov dword[x], 0x0a656c4f
  push dword[x]
  mov ecx, esp
  mov edx, 4
  int 0x80
  mov eax,1 
  mov ebx, 0
  int 0x80
```

If I got it right after **mov dword[x], 0x0a656c4f** the memory layout is :

```
  0a (higher) 
  65 
  6c 
  4f (lower)
```

because of little endianness of x86 and x points to byte whose value is **4f**.
After **push dword[x]**, there's the same picture of stack (reversed as it grows downwards) where **esp** points to **0a**

The same question is relevant to the code when

```
  mov dword[x], 0x0a656c4f
  push dword[x]
```

is replaced with:

```
push dword 0x0a656c4f
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the point of the last part of the question? The registers `ebx`, `ecx` and `edx` contain the arguments for the `write(2)` system call.

Comment: @Kerrek SB. Sorry, fixed.

Comment: Related: [Relation between endianness and stack-growth direction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18470053) - there is none; the store part of a `push` is just a regular dword store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack grows *downward*:

Before the push:

```
****
****
**** <--- ESP
```

After `push DWORD 0x0a656c4f`:

```
****
****
****            -+
0x0A             |
0x65             ^
0x6C             |
0x4F <--- ESP   -+- write(2) four bytes from here
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that "little endian" (or big endian) applies to multi-byte numbers. "hello world" isn't stored "backwards" in memory. Likewise, the stack "grows downward" in the sense that `push` decreases `esp` - the memory isn't "upside down" just because it's on the stack.

A related(?) oddity to Nasm's syntax is that character constants are assumed to be in the order you write 'em. If you were searching environment variables, for example, Nasm would expect:

```
cmp dword [esi], 'HOME'
```

Other assemblers might expect:

```
cmp dword ptr [esi], 'EMOH'
```

Mostly an issue when you're "translating" from one assembler's syntax to another's...

Comment: I don't find NASM's behaviour odd, that multi-character literals go into machine code in source order.  That matches the order they go into `db` or `dd`.  It's MASM that's weird, reversing your string for no reason as it copies it to the output.  GAS simply doesn't accept multi-character literals as integer constants in the first place.  (x86 machine code uses little-endian 32-bit immediates, so immediate stores and pushes contain the data in the same order they'll store it in.)