# Why does ESP point to [esp+0xc]?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, mingw

I'd like to learn some assembly and now I have a question where `ESP` shifts the intialized integer to during the function call of the main function.

**The C-Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main() {
    int hallo = 5;
}
```

When I compile this file with GCC and decompile it with the command
`objdump -M intel -D a.exe | grep -A20 main.`

Then it looks like this:

```
00401460 <_main>:
  401460:       55                      push   ebp
  401461:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  401463:       83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
  401466:       83 ec 10                sub    esp,0x10
  401469:       e8 42 05 00 00          call   4019b0 <___main>
  40146e:       c7 44 24 0c 05 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],0x5
  401475:       00
  401476:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  40147b:       c9                      leave
  40147c:       c3                      ret
  40147d:       90                      nop
  40147e:       90                      nop
  40147f:       90                      nop

00401480 <__setargv>:
  401480:       55                      push   ebp
  401481:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  401483:       57                      push   edi
  401484:       56                      push   esi
  401485:       53                      push   ebx
--
004019b0 <___main>:
  4019b0:       a1 28 70 40 00          mov    eax,ds:0x407028
  4019b5:       85 c0                   test   eax,eax
  4019b7:       74 07                   je     4019c0 <___main+0x10>
  4019b9:       f3 c3                   repz ret
  4019bb:       90                      nop
  4019bc:       8d 74 26 00             lea    esi,[esi+eiz*1+0x0]
  4019c0:       c7 05 28 70 40 00 01    mov    DWORD PTR ds:0x407028,0x1
  4019c7:       00 00 00
  4019ca:       eb 94                   jmp    401960 <___do_global_ctors>
  4019cc:       90                      nop
  4019cd:       90                      nop
  4019ce:       90                      nop
  4019cf:       90                      nop

004019d0 <.text>:
  4019d0:       83 ec 1c                sub    esp,0x1c
  4019d3:       8b 44 24 24             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x24]
  4019d7:       83 f8 03                cmp    eax,0x3
  4019da:       74 14                   je     4019f0 <.text+0x20>
  4019dc:       85 c0                   test   eax,eax
```

I expect that the last assembly-command is `mov DWORD PTR [esp+0xF],0x5`,
because the Stack is growing from top to bottom and because of Little Endian, the ESP must be positioned on `[esp+0xF]` to fill up the next 4 Bytes (integer) to Position `[esp+0xc]`.

Comment: PS: I am using a 64 bit CPU

Comment: The local variable might've been optimized away.

Comment: Are you asking for a detailed walkthrough of gcc's code generator? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: I don't need a detailed walkthrough of gcc's code generator. If the reason is a speficiation of gcc that it's the way it is but than my question would be why it breaks with little Endian...

Comment: The code has nothing to do with endianness and I'm confused why you think it does.

Comment: The address that `mov` takes is the first byte of the four bytes to set . moving four bytes to address 100C writes the bytes 100C,100D,100E,100F.  this is the same regardless of endianness or stack direction

Comment: Because I thought little Endian would fill up the 16-Byte-Block in reversed order. So the 0x05 would be storted in the lowest part of the block: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470053/relation-between-endianness-and-stack-growth-direction/45424788. So actually i would expect the 5 stored at [esp + 0].

Comment: What 16 byte block? we're talking about 4 bytes here. And the answer you link to is somewhere between rubbish and irrelevant. No system stack I've ever heard of would push or pop a 4-byte integer in 4 char-size steps. The code you link doesn't push or pop the `0x5` at all, it writes 4 bytes at once to a location in the stack. `mov` means to write bytes, not push.

Comment: I thought the command "sub esp, 0x10" reserves 16 Byte?

Comment: `exp` is not a register name.  This is obviously not real `objdump` output.  Please copy/paste instead of typing, especially things you don't understand and are asking about.  Anywhere, what's the label on that block that calls `___main`?  Note that it's not `_main` or `main`, it's some internal CRT startup function called `___main` with three underscores.  Unless that's a typo, too.  Although that doesn't actually matter for your question.  Unless that *is* the asm for `main` itself, with MinGW inserting a call to a startup function into `main`.

Comment: It does, but that's nothing to do with endianness . "little endian" means that bytes C,D,E,F are 5,0,0,0 respectively. "big endian" would mean they were 0,0,0,5.

Comment: @PeterCordes could you comment/answer on the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470053/relation-between-endianness-and-stack-growth-direction/45424788) OP linked? I'm no expert on the topic but the top answer seems like hogwash

Comment: @M.M: lol, yes that answer is total nonsense; I left a comment.  Will post a quick answer.

Comment: OK, I edited my Question. Now the full Assembly-Code is posted...sorry.

Comment: "esp should be positioned on esp+0xF" makes no sense... esp is esp, not esp+anything.  `mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],0x5` mean: go to where ESP points, go forward by `0xC`, then write four bytes to that location and the next 3 bytes (in increasing order).   The endianness tells you whether the bytes are 5,0,0,0 or 0,0,0,5  ; and the stack direction is irrelevant

Comment: Yeah, its true that "esp should be positioned on esp+0xF" makes no sense....But is the integer 5 (= 4 byte) now stored between [esp+0xC] and [esp+0xF] or between [esp+0xC] and [esp+0x9]? I Would say it ts stored between  [esp+0xC] and [esp+0x9]...Thank you so far.

Comment: it's stored between esp+0xC and esp+0xF  . That's how addresses work, they increase in order.

Comment: Ah ok. So the stack grows to lower addresses but when i write a chunk of 4 Bytes in an addres that it is always written in increasing order?

Comment: @M.M: I posted an answer on [Relation between endianness and stack-growth direction](//stackoverflow.com/a/56832003)

Comment: BTW: the assembly code you show here is 32 bit code, even if your CPU is a 64 bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a dword store to `[esp+0xF]` would write the 4 bytes at `[esp + 0x0f .. 0x12]`, which isn't even dword-aligned.

If you were confused by [Relation between endianness and stack-growth direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470053/relation-between-endianness-and-stack-growth-direction) and the old answers there, that's understandable; they were completely wrong so I posted a correct one.

**The address of a dword is always the lowest address of any of its component bytes.**  (This applies to big- and little-endian systems).

Reserving 16 bytes and storing to `[esp+0xc]` stores to the highest-address 4 bytes of those 16.

**The dword at `[esp+0xc]` is (in order from LSB to MSB) the bytes at addresses ESP `+0xc`, `+0xd`, `+0xe`, and `+0xf`.**

For a (hypothetical) big-endian x86 it would the same bytes, but that order would be MSB to LSB.  The address of the dword would still be `[esp+0xc]`.

None of this has any connection to `push` doing `esp-=4` instead of `esp+=4`.  Systems with upwards-growing stacks still use the lowest byte address within a word / dword as the address of that multi-byte integer.  Just like in C, the address of an array or struct is the address of the first element.  In fact that's *why* C addresses work that way.

---

Since the stack grows downward, it makes some sense that gcc would choose to put a local there, right below the saved EBP value, and leave the rest of the space unused as padding for stack alignment before a `call` (to the CRT helper function `___main`).

Even though the 32-bit Windows ABI doesn't require 16-byte stack alignment, gcc chooses to do it anyway (default of `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4` : 2^4 = 16)

---

And BTW, obviously all this noise goes away if you compile with optimization enabled.  Then main can just `ret`.  Or maybe still has to call `___main`, but can optimize away the local.

You could reduce the noise but still make GCC init a local by making it `volatile` and compiling with `-O3`.  Or pass its address to another non-inline function.

---

> Why does ESP point to [esp+0xc]?

Huh? That doesn't even make sense.  ESP points at `[esp]`.  You're actually asking why GCC chose to use the addressing mode `[esp+0xc]` rather than some other displacement.

Comment: But aren't the two Statements "No, a dword store to [esp+0xF] would write the 4 bytes at [esp + 0x0f .. 0x12], which isn't even dword-aligned."  and "Reserving 16 bytes and storing to [esp+0xc] stores to the highest-address 4 bytes of those 16. Since the stack grows downward, it makes some sense that gcc would choose to put a local there, right below the saved EBP value..." contradictory? If [esp+0xF] would write the 4 bytes at [esp + 0x0f .. 0x12], then [esp+0xc] would write the 4 bytes at [esp + 0xc .. 0x9]???

Comment: @LarsLafleur you seem confused about what "the stack grows downwards" means.  The address after esp+0xC is esp+0xD , that is a fact of how memory addressing is defined.  The stack direction is NOTHING WHATSOEVER to do with that.

Comment: I would completly agree to you. So esp+0xC  goes upwards, no matter what stack direction is. But then " [esp+0xF] would write the 4 bytes at [esp + 0x0f .. 0x12]" couldn't be true, because [esp+0xF] would write the 4 bytes at [esp + 0xF .. 0x12], wouldn't it?

Comment: But I think i have understood why little Edian is irrelevant, because we write the 4 bytes from [esp+0xc] to [esp+0xF] (because thats  memory addressing is defined) and within this 4 bytes, the 5 is stored as little Endian...right???

Comment: @LarsLafleur Huh? You wrote "but then 'THING' couldn't be true because SAME THING",  , not sure what your question is.

Comment: Sorry, that was an misunderstanding. I didn't read the answer correctly.

Comment: @LarsLafleur yes, little endian refers to the significance of bytes used to store an integer in that space